# How to create a questionnaire grouped by category in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following structure and, I need to create one Form that has many sections and inside them many categories and questions inside categories.

How can I create a Structure in Xamarin like:

```
 Section -1
 + Category-1- 
         Questions 1
             Answers: Y/N
         Questions n
             Answers: Y/N
Category-2- 
         Questions
         Answers: Y/N

Section -2

Section -3

-....

-Section-n
   Category-n- 
         Questions n
            Answers: Y/N
         Questions n
            Answers: Y/N
   Category -n- 
         Questions n
            Answers: Y/N
```

Example:

[image: a busy cat]

```
Structure:

"sections": [
      {
        "sectionID": "string",            
        "sectionName": "string",
        "startDateSection": "2019-10-04T19:23:23.478Z",
        "categories": [
          {
            "categoryID": "string",            
            "categoryName": "string",
            "questions": [
              {
                "questionID": "string",
                "description": "string",
                "mandatory": true,
                "answers": [
                  {
                    "answerID": "string",
                    "answer": "string",
                    "dateInserted": "2019-10-04T19:23:23.479Z",
                    "dateModified": "2019-10-04T19:23:23.479Z",
                    "questionID": "string",
                    "startDateQuestion": "2019-10-04T19:23:23.479Z",
                    "inspectionsID": "string",
                    "medias": [
                      {

                        "fileAddress": "string",
                        "dateInserted": "2019-10-04T19:23:23.479Z",
                        "answerID": "string"
                      }
                    ],
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: This is the third variation of this question you've asked this week.

Comment: I am trying to provide more information that what I need. The first questions were about how to create dynamic pages. Could you help me with my question? I really appreciate it, and sorry I am new using Stackoverflow.

Comment: it is an improvement over your previous attempts, but it's still incredibly broad.  This is a pretty complex problem, I could write pages on how to approach it.  You should really break it down into simpler chunks and figure out how to solve each one before moving onto the next part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your sections are different [Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/pages) and I don't see categories in the image.

But it would make sense to place the Questions and Answers in a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) and perhaps group them together using headers that will display the category.

Inside the ListView, you could probably use a [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) for the Layout of the ListView cell, to display the questions and answers the way you want